# Ошибка при php авторизации

Tags: php

делаю авторизацию на сайте по урокам Хауди-хо. Вроде сделал всё правильно, но выдаёт ошибку

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in W:\domains\site.com\handle.php on line 14

Тут происходит поиск пользователя.

```php
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'besit');
if(conection == false)
{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
$pas = $_POST['password'];
$log = $_POST['login'];
echo $log . " " . $pas . " Its pasand log<br>";
$count = mysqli_query($connection,  "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = '$log'");
echo ">" . $count ."<";
 if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 0)
 {
  echo "Не правильное имя пользователя, или пароль."
}
 else
 {
    echo "Вы успешно авторизавались!";
 }
```

Тут мы вводим пароль.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'besit');
if(conection == false)
{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
echo "мы подключились!";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `articles`");
?>
<?php
while (($staties = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)))
{
    echo $staties['title'] . '<br>' . $staties['text'] . '<br>';
}

 ?>
 <form method="POST" action="/handle.php">
    <input type ="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login">
    <input type ="text" placeholder="Папроль"name="password"><hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как там у Хауди, но у тебя..Может для начала стоит начать отсюда ?
**ТВОЙ КОД**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'besit');
if(conection == false)
{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

1) $co**nn**ection != co**n**ection
2) conection == false - o.O

И т.д

Может лучше сделать вот так ?

```
$bds = new mysqli('ХОСТ', 'ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛь', 'ПАРОЛЬ', 'БАЗА ДАННЫХ');
if ($bds->connect_errno) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . $bds->connect_errno);
}
```

**Продолжение:**
Накидал пример, который судя по всему должен был быть у топикстартера..В моем случае все работает.

```
$name = 'FJXXga2SA';


$row = $bds->query("SELECT * FROM таблица WHERE столбец='$name'");
if ($row->num_rows == 0)
{
    echo 'Нет совпадений';
    //Какой нибудь код

}else{
    echo 'Совпадений:'.$row->num_rows;
    //Какой нибудь код
}
```

Comment: Это конечно хорошее замечание. Но оно не вызывает указанную топикстартером ошибку.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, решив тем самым ошибку топикстартера. Дело за малым ($_POST и т.п).